# Erro de cache ao deploiar no app engine, porém localmente funciona!

Tags: spring-boot, spring-mvc, cache, google-app-engine

Minha aplicação `SpringBoot` funciona localmente, mas quando realizo o `deploy` no `Appengine` ela não sobre pois da erro `500`, estou utilizando uma implementação do `EHCACHE` no padrão `JSR-107` pois pelo que li é o único formato de padrão de cache que o `AppEngine` suporta. Ao finalizar o `deploy` é gerada a seguinte StackTrace na minha seção de registros.

```
Uncaught exception from servlet
java.util.ServiceConfigurationError: javax.cache.spi.CachingProvider: Provider org.ehcache.jsr107.EhcacheCachingProvider could not be instantiated
    at java.util.ServiceLoader.fail(ServiceLoader.java:232)
    at java.util.ServiceLoader.access$100(ServiceLoader.java:185)
    at java.util.ServiceLoader$LazyIterator.nextService(ServiceLoader.java:384)
    at java.util.ServiceLoader$LazyIterator.next(ServiceLoader.java:404)
    at java.util.ServiceLoader$1.next(ServiceLoader.java:480)
    at javax.cache.Caching$CachingProviderRegistry$1.run(Caching.java:438)
    at javax.cache.Caching$CachingProviderRegistry$1.run(Caching.java:432)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.cache.Caching$CachingProviderRegistry.getCachingProviders(Caching.java:432)
    at javax.cache.Caching$CachingProviderRegistry.getCachingProviders(Caching.java:400)
    at javax.cache.Caching.getCachingProviders(Caching.java:178)
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.cache.JCacheCacheConfiguration$JCacheProviderAvailableCondition.getMatchOutcome(JCacheCacheConfiguration.java:203)
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.AbstractNestedCondition$MemberOutcomes.getConditionOutcome(AbstractNestedCondition.java:191)
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.AbstractNestedCondition$MemberOutcomes.<init>(AbstractNestedCondition.java:184)
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.AbstractNestedCondition$MemberConditions.lambda$getMatchOutcomes$0(AbstractNestedCondition.java:162)
    at java.util.Map.forEach(Map.java:630)
    at java.util.Collections$UnmodifiableMap.forEach(Collections.java:1505)
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.AbstractNestedCondition$MemberConditions.getMatchOutcomes(AbstractNestedCondition.java:162)
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.AbstractNestedCondition$MemberMatchOutcomes.<init>(AbstractNestedCondition.java:81)
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.AbstractNestedCondition.getMatchOutcome(AbstractNestedCondition.java:65)
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.SpringBootCondition.matches(SpringBootCondition.java:47)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConditionEvaluator.shouldSkip(ConditionEvaluator.java:108)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader$TrackedConditionEvaluator.shouldSkip(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:441)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitionsForConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:128)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:117)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.processConfigBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:328)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.postProcessBeanDefinitionRegistry(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:233)
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:273)
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:93)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:694)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:532)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:140)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:759)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:395)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:327)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.SpringBootServletInitializer.run(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:155)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.SpringBootServletInitializer.createRootApplicationContext(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:135)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.SpringBootServletInitializer.onStartup(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:87)
    at org.springframework.web.SpringServletContainerInitializer.onStartup(SpringServletContainerInitializer.java:172)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.plus.annotation.ContainerInitializer.callStartup(ContainerInitializer.java:140)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.annotations.ServletContainerInitializersStarter.doStart(ServletContainerInitializersStarter.java:63)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.startContext(ServletContextHandler.java:330)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startWebapp(WebAppContext.java:1406)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty9.AppEngineWebAppContext.startWebapp(AppEngineWebAppContext.java:175)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1368)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:778)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.doStart(ServletContextHandler.java:262)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:522)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty9.AppEngineWebAppContext.doStart(AppEngineWebAppContext.java:120)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty9.AppVersionHandlerMap.createHandler(AppVersionHandlerMap.java:240)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty9.AppVersionHandlerMap.getHandler(AppVersionHandlerMap.java:178)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty9.JettyServletEngineAdapter.serviceRequest(JettyServletEngineAdapter.java:120)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.JavaRuntime$RequestRunnable.dispatchServletRequest(JavaRuntime.java:722)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.JavaRuntime$RequestRunnable.dispatchRequest(JavaRuntime.java:685)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.JavaRuntime$RequestRunnable.run(JavaRuntime.java:655)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.JavaRuntime$NullSandboxRequestRunnable.run(JavaRuntime.java:847)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.ThreadGroupPool$PoolEntry.run(ThreadGroupPool.java:270)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: class org.ehcache.jsr107.Eh107CacheManager has class javax.cache.CacheManager as interface
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:763)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:467)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:73)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:368)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:362)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:361)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.ApplicationClassLoader.findClass(ApplicationClassLoader.java:135)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredConstructors(Class.java:2673)
    at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:3077)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:413)
    at java.util.ServiceLoader$LazyIterator.nextService(ServiceLoader.java:380)
    ... 57 more
```

Estou utilizando as seguintes dependências de CACHE:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-cache</artifactId>
    <version>${springframework.version}</version>
</dependency>
<!-- EH CACHE -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.ehcache</groupId>
    <artifactId>ehcache</artifactId>
    <version>3.5.2</version>
</dependency>
<!-- JCACHE PARA O PADRÃO JSR 107 -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.cache</groupId>
    <artifactId>cache-api</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Este é meu arquivo de configuração do ehcache:

```
<config 
    xmlns:jsr107='http://www.ehcache.org/v3/jsr107'
    xmlns='http://www.ehcache.org/v3'>

    <service>
        <jsr107:defaults>
            <jsr107:cache name="consultarPorEmail"
                template="heap-cache" />
        </jsr107:defaults>
    </service>

    <cache-template name="heap-cache">
        <resources>
            <heap unit="entries">2000</heap>
            <offheap unit="MB">100</offheap>
        </resources>
    </cache-template>
</config>
```

E aqui estão as configuração de jcache do arquivo application.properties:

```
spring.cache.jcache.config=classpath:ehcache.xml 
spring.cache.cache-names=consultarPorEmail
```

Já estou parado neste problema há dias, se puderem por favor me ajudem...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Olá o problema estava em um conflito de dependências, a dependência do EHCACHE estava dando conflito com dependência do JCACHE,

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.ehcache</groupId>
    <artifactId>ehcache</artifactId>
    <version>3.5.2</version>
</dependency>
<!-- JCACHE PARA O PADRÃO JSR 107 -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.cache</groupId>
    <artifactId>cache-api</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Então bastou apagar a dependência do EHCACHE que funcionou, ficando então desta maneira:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.cache</groupId>
    <artifactId>cache-api</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Só que isso não resolveu 100% dos meus problemas, já que a stack trace desapareceu, porém o erro `500` ainda ocorre, assim que eu conseguir resolver este outro problema volto e posto a solução.